# Doing a ShuffleSplit with GridSearchCV

Tags: python, keras, scikit-learn, data-science

I'm trying to do a ShuffleSplit with a GridSearchCV in scikit-learn.

Here's my MWE, which is a modification to what one can find in the Deep Learning with Python book, by François Chollet. In the book, he doesn't use scikit-learn.

```
from keras import models
from keras import layers
import numpy as np
from sklearn.model_selection import GridSearchCV
from keras.wrappers.scikit_learn import KerasRegressor
from sklearn.metrics import mean_squared_error
from sklearn.model_selection import ShuffleSplit

from keras.datasets import boston_housing
(train_data,train_targets),(test_data,test_targets)=boston_housing.load_data()

mean=np.mean(train_data)
std=np.std(train_data)

train_data_norm=(train_data-mean)/std
test_data_norm=(test_data-mean)/std

def build_model():
    model=models.Sequential()
    model.add(layers.Dense(64,activation="relu",
                          input_shape=(train_data_norm.shape[1],)))
    model.add(layers.Dense(64,activation="relu"))
    model.add(layers.Dense(1))
    model.compile(optimizer='rmsprop',loss="mse",metrics=["mae"])
    return model 

model=KerasRegressor(build_fn=build_model,epochs=30,verbose=0)

param_grid = {"epochs":range(1,11)}

ss = ShuffleSplit(n_splits=4, test_size=0.1, random_state=0)

grid_model=GridSearchCV(model,param_grid,cv=ss,n_jobs=-1,scoring='neg_mean_squared_error')

grid_model.fit(train_data, train_targets)

mean_squared_error(grid_model.predict(test_data),test_targets)
```

One thing I find strange is that I when using `ShuffleSplit`, I have to define again the size of my test data, which I'll apply only to  `(train_data,train_targets)` when fitting the model. Also, I thought that using `ShuffleSplit` would stabilise the MSE prediction performance, when compared to a simple CV, but the opposite happens. If I use

```
grid_model=GridSearchCV(model,param_grid,cv=4,n_jobs=-1,scoring='neg_mean_squared_error')
```

instead, then I'll have a smaller MSE when predicting for the `test_data`.

Am I coding correctly the use of a ShuffleSplit in GridSearchCV?

Comment: What *exactly* is your issue and your *question*?

Comment: @desertnaut I've edited my question. Thanks for the making me notice it.

Comment: "*Am I coding and proceeding  correctly?*" is way too vague and broad, and bound to be closed as such. Please, instead of informing us about things you may find strange, ask a *specific* question.

Comment: @desertnaut what about now?

Comment: My objective is to understand whether my code makes a semantic error or not... Since if it were merely a syntatical one, Python would warn me about it.